# Getting Cross-Site Request Forgery error in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, veracode

I'm getting CSRF exception for the below code.  Please advise the solution to fix this issue.

```java
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
.and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPointToken)
.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
.and().cors().and().csrf().disable();
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: its captured as CRLF violation in Veracode report

Comment: What exactly does it show? You shouldn't disable csrf for normal applications. See [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/csrf-thymeleaf-with-spring-security).